How to pull GCR images from a GCE instance through GitHub Actions
I am implementing my GitHub Action workflow file which is supposed to update my docker images hosted on GCR, and then log into my GCE instance to pull the newly updated images with docker compose.
The problem is I am getting an error at docker compose pull :
err: frontend Error Head "https://europe-west9-docker.pkg.dev/v2/***/registry/frontend/manifests/latest": unauthorized: authentication failed

If I ssh into my GCE instance, and run : sudo gcloud auth login, follow instructions to login and then run the workflow file, it succeeds to pull the images.
What changes can I make to my git actions file so that I don’t need to auth login in my VM for it to pull my images ?
Here is what my git action workflow file looks like:
name: Deploy App on Dev Env

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'develop'

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Google Cloud SDK (service with admin rights for GCR)
      uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0
      with:
        project_id: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_PROJECT }}
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}
        export_default_credentials: true

    - name: Authenticate Docker with GCR
      run: |
        gcloud auth configure-docker europe-west9-docker.pkg.dev

    - name: Build and push backend Docker image
      env:
        GOOGLE_PROJECT: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_PROJECT }}
      run: |
        docker build -f Dockerfile.backend -t europe-west9-docker.pkg.dev/$GOOGLE_PROJECT/registry/backend:latest .
        docker push europe-west9-docker.pkg.dev/$GOOGLE_PROJECT/registry/backend:latest

    - name: Build and push frontend Docker image
      env:
        GOOGLE_PROJECT: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_PROJECT }}
      run: |
        docker build -f frontend/Dockerfile -t europe-west9-docker.pkg.dev/$GOOGLE_PROJECT/registry/frontend:latest frontend/
        docker push europe-west9-docker.pkg.dev/$GOOGLE_PROJECT/registry/frontend:latest

    - name: Deploy to GCP VM
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.5
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.GCP_VM_IP }}
        username: ${{ secrets.GCP_VM_USER }}
        key: ${{ secrets.GCP_VM_SSH_KEY }}
        script: |
          sudo docker compose pull
          sudo docker compose up -d --remove-orphans
          sudo docker image prune -a -f

I've been looking for ways to authenticate to my instance through git actions, but couldn't find one that works.

gcloud auth login is for user authentication. are you using service account?

If you're not yet using a service account, try using a service account and add an admin role , which may resolve the issue.

Make sure you are using a service account, which has the necessary permissions to pull images from the GCR repository, Assign the Storage Object Viewer role or if you want to perform any action choose Admin role. Refer to the official GCP document on Authenticate to IAM for more details.

If you are using email Id to login, try using Docker id (username and password) to login Docker Hub which also may cause authentication issues. And try to restart the docker,  which helps to provide proper configuration. And also refer to this GCP document for push and pull the images with docker.

@chlouska I have posted the above comments as an answer. Can you check and revert back if you are still facing the issue. What should I do when someone answers my question?

@KokilaR Thanks for the suggestions. However, I have a service account that I use for pushing images to GCR. The issue I still have is about the step 'Deploy to GCP VM'. I wonder if there is a way to connect to the VM and login with my gcp admin credentials to pull the images from GCR.

@chlouska, I have updated the answer based on your response.Let me know if the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries

Yes.Based on your comments, using SSH we are able to login using GCP admin credentials. If you are using Linux Compute Engine, SSH login using a password is disabled on newly created instance. By using the below way it can be enabled accordingly.
To enable SSH password authentication, you must SSH in as root to edit the file /etc/ssh/sshd\_config and change the line PasswordAuthentication no to PasswordAuthentication yes. After making the change, Save and restart the SSH service by running the following command as root: sudo service ssh restart.

This does not work either unfortunately. What would be needed is to ssh into the VM and run the command cloud auth login in GitHub action. The issue with that is that the command auth login asks to confirm identity by requesting to copy a code available at a given link and I would need to bypass this way of login in git actions.
